# Resharper Plugin Development Project Setup - gradle-intellij-plugin Cannot Create Plugin From File error

Tags: .net, gradle, resharper, intellij-plugin, rider

I'm diving into developing plugins for the Resharper Platform and while I'm understanding the concepts I'm having some trouble with the initial project setup. I've gone through much of the documentation and am hitting some snags.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Rider Version: 2020.1.4
Dotnet: 3.1.302

For starters I'm using the Jetbrains Resharper Plugin Template

https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-rider-plugin

After building the solution with no errors I run the gradlew task included with the project template. It starts the sandbox IDE without issues but looking at the dev log I seem to be receiving these errors.

```
> Configure project :
[gradle-intellij-plugin :testplugin] Cannot read builtin registry cache. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[gradle-intellij-plugin :testplugin] Cannot create plugin from file (/home/fibonascii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.rider/riderRD/2020.1.0/6e8e386246a18b9cf81176ab8c23424dfcaec408/riderRD-2020.1.0/plugins/rider-cpp): Invalid plugin descriptor 'plugin.xml': failed to resolve <xi:include>. Not found document '/META-INF/CidrDebuggerPlugin.xml' referenced in <xi:include href="/META-INF/CidrDebuggerPlugin.xml", xpointer="xpointer(/idea-plugin/*)"/>. <xi:fallback> element is not provided. (at plugin.xml)
```

I don't fully understand this error.

I haven't been able to track down much information on this. It doesn't seem to be related to the contents of plugin.xml  directly but rather to a missing reference of some sort.

Plugin.xml

```
  <id>testplugin-rider</id>
  <name>TestPlugin</name>
  <version>_PLACEHOLDER_</version>
  <vendor url="https://project-url">Author</vendor>
  <idea-version since-build="_PLACEHOLDER_" until-build="_PLACEHOLDER_" />
  <depends>com.intellij.modules.rider</depends>

  <description>
<![CDATA[
<p>Sample description</p>
]]>
  </description>
  
</idea-plugin>
```

Can someone with experience in development on the ReSharper Platform help me understand this error? I will admit I'm not super experienced in Gradle or the Java platform so I'm doing some research on standard IntelliJ development as well as research on Gradle to get a better understanding of these concepts as I am primarily a .NET, Python, and GoLang developer. I've gone through all the documents explaining the custom Resharper protocol and how communication between Rider and Resharper works and this all makes sense to me. I understand the component model and general development on the platform but this error seems to be escaping me. My apologies if this is something that could easily be understood from basic gradle setup but I haven't been able to find anything on this error so far.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am having the same issue - I don't reference a "CidrDebuggerPlugin.xml" anywhere in my entire project, and this file practically doesn't exist doing a Google search. Did you ever get anywhere with this? This plugin dev environment is such a mess.

Comment: @lmcintyre it's a long story but I basically had to take the last 8 months off from computing and so I never got to get back to this but I'm getting back into this project. Whenever I come up with a resolution I'm going to answer this question and I'll tag you in it

Comment: I actually solved this be deleting the "rider-cpp" folder in the build/Rider-{ver}/plugins/ folder. If your plugin requires that, it might be necessary to keep. But that worked for me, as this error was preventing my plugin jar from building.